# Meteorite (mrt) command does nothing

Tags: linux, node.js, meteor, linux-mint, meteorite

I just had to reinstall linux to my computer, so I've been setting up my development environment again. I was able to use Meteor with Meteorite before, but now the `mrt` command doesn't do anything. It doesn't throw an error or anything, I installed it with `sudo -H npm install -g meteorite` and then, when I type `mrt`, it looks like this:

```
~ $ mrt
~ $
```

I saw a few similar issues, but no solutions. I think I'm going to try building it myself, but I was hoping someone might already have the answer

Comment: @JimGarrison no, this is definitely a programming question. See the `meteor` tag.

Comment: What's your version of node, npm, meteor, meteorite?

Comment: This seems to be about installing something.  I don't see any code.

Comment: `Node: v0.10.15`  `npm: 1.3.5`  `meteor:  0.6.4.1`  `meteorite: 0.6.8`

Comment: give us the result of `which mrt`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

i had the same problem under ubuntu.
mrt was looking for an executable node (which was supposed to be  nodejs), but in ubuntu if you look at the package node, you get:

```
$ apt-cache show node
Package: node
Priority: optional
Section: universe/hamradio
Installed-Size: 38
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian Hamradio Maintainers <debian-hams@lists.debian.org>
Architecture: all
Version: 0.3.2-7.4
Depends: ax25-node
Conflicts: nodejs-legacy
Filename: pool/universe/n/node/node_0.3.2-7.4_all.deb
Size: 1284
MD5sum: 7385a0f5916e03d9143459ca4706f0ec
SHA1: bf7aa087db81475636897ff39de344754ce1415b
SHA256: 9756770f771bcc4183cffa622f89e21a585be96bd4de27024b0a7cb167f310ad
Description-en: Amateur Packet Radio Node program (transitional package)
 The existing node package has been renamed to ax25-node. This transitional
 package exists to ease the upgrade path for existing users.
Description-md5: 1278ed271672fd829c99361f93f468da
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
```

which actually is NOT nodejs. Basically mrt was calling the wrong executable.
I have fixed in the following way:

- remove node: `sudo apt-get remove node`
- locate nodejs executable: run `which nodejs`. to me returned `/usr/bin/nodejs`
- create a link to node: `ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node`

Now mrt calls correctly nodejs and everything works